# Requesting JSON information from API. Corona

Tags: json, api, coronasdk

I'm trying to make an app where I will gather information from a json api http://pool-x.eu/api, and print information easly bo choosing parameter.

What is the easiest way to print each of the informations?

Was thinking something in the way of making the information a string, and then request each of the parameters that way, but I don't know if that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a sample code to decode the json data i just happen to make a json text file out if the link you gave and decode it hope it helps

```
local json = require "json"
local txt
local path = system.pathForFile( "json.txt", system.ResourceDirectory )

local file = io.open( path, "r" )
for line in file:lines() do
txt = line
end
print(txt)
local t = json.decode( txt )
print(t["pool_name"])
print(t["hashrate"])
print(t["workers"])
print(t["share_this_round"])
print(t["last_block"])
print(t["network_hashrate"])
```

Comment: And how would I then be able to access each of the paramters and print them in the application?And where do I add the API-link?

Comment: just use a network request on corona and get the response of the url you visit for the link that you give it will return the json data
here may this will be useful http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html